# The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.Byte' and 'System.Byte'

Tags: c#, expression

I am working on a project that constructs lambda expressions dynamically.
In s specific scenario I've constructed dynamically an expression which equals to this one:

> byte i = 1;
>    byte j = 1;
>   var firstConstant = Expression.Constant(i);
>  
>   var secondConstant = Expression.Constant(j);
>   var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Add(firstConstant, secondConstant));
>   lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();

I Know that primitive types don't have operators overloading and the compiler actually cast the variables/constants to int before the addition and the result back to byte which i don't therefore the exception is being raised. 
My question is what is the logic to perform add operations without knowing the types and without loosing some data in case I need to handle float point types?

Comment: I've also noticed that with other types its actually works - two constants of short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I'd conditionally test the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.type.aspx) of each operand to see whether it's `byte`, `sbyte` etc, and introduce an `Expression.Convert` if necessary.

It's probably worth looking at what the C# compiler generates for:

```
Expression<Func<byte, byte, int>> expr = (a, b) => a + b;
```

... then try to get your own code to generate the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
byte i = 1; 
byte j = 1; 
var firstConstant = Expression.Constant(i.GetType () == typeof (Byte) ? (int) i : i); 
var secondConstant = Expression.Constant(j.GetType () == typeof (Byte) ? (int) j : j);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Add(firstConstant, secondConstant));    
lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

this way you don't loose anything if it is something other than a byte...
Also note that doing `byte r = i + j;` gives you compile time error about "no automatic conversion from int to byte".

Comment: I know that I can do that. My Question was whether there is a system for checking the types that can be handled with the add operation or not, and why add operation is valid with some types and invalid with others?

Comment: you can use Reflection on the types of your variables to see whether they support the Add method/operator and follow the description of how Expression.Add itself does this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354402.aspx)... another option is to provide the Method to perform the operation as MethodInfo object as third parameter to Expression.Add .

Answer (score 0):

That might not be possible. The Expression.Add does not perform overflow checking and it looks for the implementation of the Binary + operator. The other overload allows to specify the MethodInfo to select the method to perform the Add.

If you can ensure that all your types going in, support this method you can use the above logic. It does work for short because the binary + operator is defined. The same is not present for the System.Byte class and hence you have the problem. Even with the Compiler implementation, you cannot do:

```
byte i = 1;
byte j = 2;
byte sum = i+j; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: According to msdn there are no operators overloading in short http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.aspx